Error Fetching YouTube Transcript Using YouTubeTranscriptApi on Server but Works Locally
I'm encountering an issue where the YouTubeTranscriptApi library works perfectly on my local machine but fails when run on the server. The script I'm using is as follows:
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

video_id = 'DxL2HoqLbyA'
try:
    transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)
    print(transcript)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

When executed on the server, it throws an error, but it runs without issues on my local setup. Here is the exact error message I receive on the server:Failed to retrieve transcript:

Could not retrieve a transcript for the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxL2HoqLbyA! This is most likely caused by:
Subtitles are disabled for this video
If you are sure that the described cause is not responsible for this error and that a transcript should be retrievable, please create an issue at https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api/issues. Please add which version of youtube_transcript_api you are using and provide the information needed to replicate the error. Also make sure that there are no open issues which already describe your problem!

I attempted to use a proxy library to bypass the connection issue, but this resulted in a new error. The error message I received is:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.youtube.com', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /watch?v=DxL2HoqLbyA
(Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy',
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
0x101b62510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61]
Connection refused')))

This indicates that the proxy connection could not be established. Despite configuring various proxy settings and trying different regions on my AWS EC2 instance, I am unable to connect to the YouTube API through the proxy. I expected that resolving the proxy connection issue would allow me to successfully retrieve the transcript on the server, similar to how it works locally.
Additionally, I attempted to solve the problem using Node.js as an alternative approach, but the issue persists.

Could you provide the details about your infrastructure on the server-side? This sounds like it could be an issue with the connectivity.
I've ran the same python commands in the equivalent javascript code locally and everything seems to work fine. I can extract the captions json that the get_transcripts() function should extract. The only place that throws the your error does so if either 1) the returned HTML does not contain "captions": or 2) transcripts are not within the request's response. I'm guessing that returned HTML is likely not what you get when making requests locally.

Hi @MarceliWac,
Thank you for your help. It looks like IP blocking is causing issues with retrieving YouTube transcripts. Many others are having similar problems, as mentioned in this https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api/issues/303.
Since the problem seems related to connectivity and proxies, I’m trying to set up a proxy or VPN on my AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I’m not sure how to do this. Could you please guide me on how to configure a proxy or VPN on my server?

actual HTTP proxy setup for an Ubuntu server is relatively easy, but you probably don't need to do that since YouTube Transcript API supports proxy configuration. As far as what proxy server you should use, that probably depends more on why the requests to YouTube are being blocked to begin with. I'm unfamiliar with YouTube Transcript API, so you will probably have more luck on their Github Discussions page.

YT seems to be blocking the static ip of your server. It has implemented this change a few weeks ago.
